# Are there jurisdictions where a premises search warrant cannot be executed without the occupier present?

Tags: warrant

Related (but not the same): [Does the renter/owner of the home have to be present for a search warrant?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/does-the-renter-owner-of-the-home-have-to-be-present-for-a-search-warrant)

Also per a comment on accepted answer on this question: [Can I tell police to wait and call a lawyer when served with a search warrant?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89973/can-i-tell-police-to-wait-and-call-a-lawyer-when-served-with-a-search-warrant)

From my personal experience previously working with police in England, when a premises search warrant is executed (house/flat/garden/etc), the legal owner and/or occupier do not need to be present.  If nobody is present, police would force entry, execute the warrant, leave relevant paperwork inside the premises for the owner/occupier to easily find, make premises safe (e.g. board it up or install new locks/etc.) and leave.

Probably many/most jurisdictions have similar rules.

My question is whether there are any jurisdictions where search warrant cannot be legally executed if the owner/occupier is not present.

Comment: I hesitate to give this as an answer, but it's not unheard of for criminals to flee or be incarcerated prior to granting of a warrant to search property for evidence of a crime, so I would expect this to be a no.

Comment: This would seem like a big loophole: just never go home, and the police will never be able to get the evidence that's there.